# I am not able to hollow out this object (newbie)

Tags: modeling, 3d-printing

This should be very easy but I am not able to get this to work. I have mainly used Solidworks in the past & I am new to Blender.

I'm trying to 3D print the planets from the NASA data. For example, I downloaded and imported a glTF file from here
https://solarsystem.nasa.gov/resources/2375/jupiter-3d-model/

I scaled it 0.01 since you can't import large files to Shapeways.

I then added the Solidify modifier, made the thickness 4mm, offset -1, even thickness. The rim option checked and unchecked didn't seem to make a wall thickness.

I added a cylinder to make a hole on the top, which is needed for cost effective 3d printing (you need a hold for sandstone and a hollow object). I used boolean to subtract that out.

After I created this hole, I can see there is no wall thickness to my planet. I've watched a few YouTube tutorials on hollowing out a model and I'm not getting what I am missing.

Maybe it's this type of import file? Some setting I'm not getting since I'm a newbie?

I was inspired to do this by this designer
https://www.littleplanetfactory.com/
I tried messaging him on what software he uses but no response.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

Answer (score 1):

Hard to say why your boolean doesn't work, but you can create your hole without. First in *Edit* mode select all and <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>J</kbd> to untriangulate, <kbd>M</kbd> to *Merge by Distance* (you have overlapping vertices), then select 4 faces on the top:

[image]

Then inset with <kbd>i</kbd>, enable the *LoopTools* addon and right click > *LoopTools > Circle*:

[image]

Delete the faces and give your object a *Solidify* modifier:

[image]

If your object needs to be rounder, give it a *Bevel* and a *Subdivision Surface* modifier, increase the bevel *Angle* value to keep the hole round:

[image]

If the hole needs to be small, select only one face, inset, subdivide, *LoopTools > Circle* and delete:

[image]

Before printing of course you'll need to apply the modifiers (and also I guess create some legs?)

Comment: Thank you!! Your pics look like what I'm aiming for.